# How to write a generator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, generator

In Python, we can write something like this to generate all positive integers:

```
def integer():
  count = 0
  while True:
    count += 1
    yield count
```

Is there a way to write a similar generator in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

It's very similar:

```
def integer
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    n = 0
    loop do
      y << n
      n += 1
    end
  end
end
```

That can be used like this:

```
integer.take(20).inject(&:+)
# => 190
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a *lazy enumerator*. In Ruby 2.3.1 (and at least as far back as Ruby 2.2.0), you can make one yourself by mixing in [Enumerator::Lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html).

However, if all you want is an infinite stream of integers, you could just use a Range object. For example:

```
(1 .. Float::INFINITY).take 10
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```